# Открытие нового окна

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

У меня в приложении 2 кнопки: "1" и "2". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на каждую кнопку открывалась новая пустая форма?

Comment: Читайте про UIViewController, UINavigationController

Comment: Что именно отвечает за новую форму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берем вот эту [сылку](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), забываем на часа три о существовании мира и проводим глубокий анализ прочитанного. Да прибудет с вами сила вьюконтроллера :)

Comment: Лучше http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457 ,